# jquery ajax not success nor error or complete functions ever called

Tags: jquery, android-emulator

The following code runs fine in Chrome. But silently fails on Android emulator. Function beforeSend executes, but not success, complete or error function are ever called. Any ideas? Android app has network permission in manifest.
Best regards.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Login').click(function () {
        var ServiceUser = { Username: $('#UserName').val(), Password: $('#Password').val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: url + 'LoginService',
            data: JSON.stringify({ serviceUser: ServiceUser }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.LoginResult == true) {
                    $.mobile.changePage("index.html",null,true,true); 
                }else {
                    alert("Login error");
                    $("#Error").html('Credenciales invalidas.');
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function(x) {    
                alert("Before execute call");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert('Error: ' + error);
                $("#Error").html(status);
                console.log("Error status: " + status);
                console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
                console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
                console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
                console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                alert(textStatus);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URL that you are posting to is correct, I have had several problems with url's and mobile devices, it seems to go a bit random sometimes when deployed.

Comment: Hello Hazza. Thanks for your response. url is defined in a variable, in order to switch from chrome + visual studio to android-emulator +  visual studio  
[code]
// Global vars
var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:2795/';
//var url = 'http://localhost:2795/';
[code]

What really stuck me is that there is no error, no success.. :-(

Comment: try using 'GET' instead of 'POST'?

Comment: Hello Haza
This is a login method, need to be post. I don't want user credentials to be cached in browser history, proxy..
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you whitelisted the URL?